# nuget can't download packages

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

So I've been dealing with this for about a month and my IT team hasn't been very helpful.

**Heres the deal:**

I have a bunch of nuget packages on an application I'm getting from a third party development team but for the sake of ease I'm going to use the ContosoUniversity sample MVC solution as the issues is present there as well.

This project needs antlr vr 3.4.1.9004, which nuget has to get. If i leave the source as is "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2" I get an error of "NuGet Package restore failed for project ContosoUniversity: Unable to find version '3.4.1.9004' of package 'Antlr'.." IF i did a little deeper I also get this error in the "manage NuGet Packages" dialog that reads "The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme.

So I changed it to http://www.nuget.org/api/v2 as per a stackoverflow question suggested. and then I get a 404. I'm at a loss I'm not sure if this is a proxy thing or what. P.S. This does not happen on a VM I have set up in my company network, which makes it so much more annoying..

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it just with this specifig package, can you download another? Did you check the proxy option for nuget in Visual Studio options?

Comment: This is with every package so far I've tried, nhibernate, MVC3, pretty much everything. Just so I make sure what option your referring to, where is that "proxy option"?